# Android widgets properties popups not showing in Eclipse on Mac OS Lion

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, properties, popup

Is it me or is it bug in Eclipse (Indigo Service Release 1) running on Mac OS Lion , that when in XML layout design mode, when I select any property of widget, its not displaying popup nor the drop down list, which is normally displayed.

I have attached screen shot in which I am clicking the combo box but its not showing me the properties drop down.

I only can see popups by pressing "Alt/Option" key and then clicking, but its annoying.
Also I am using JDK 6.

I have checked with my friend's Mac, the popups are working perfectly there without the need of pressing "Alt/option" key.

[image]

Comment: what version of eclipse? 3.7 or 3.7.1? What version of ADT plugin?

Comment: @FredGrott, I am using Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 1, ADT 16

Comment: is no one facing this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Mac OS Lion and the issue is resolved. But I have no clue why it happened, it was not eclipse issue it was problem of Mac OS Lion, what I think it might has happened because of running OnyX software.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the old good turn Eclipse off/on? For on Mac you can work on it for a months  without quitting, and Eclipse is not free of such cumulating errors. I am facing some of such errors in debugger or LogCat and am simply trying to take it in a stoical way. Even seriosly thinking on a change to IntelliJ Idea IDE.

Have you tried in that description form of a XML file to check the version of the Android? Versions different from the real or from that of the application can cause terrible things.

Comment: And have you checked the Android versions set for the widget and on the Emulator? And turning Eclipse on/off? (sorry for talking about obvious hings but we people often forget them)

Comment: Eclipse simply IS buggish. The only solution I see is to report it as a bug to Eclipse community.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the component tree, then click on the desired widget (like framelayout or any of your textviews...). You will see their properties in the right bottom corner.